# element stay at top when scrolling vertically not horizontally

Tags: html, css

so i'm working on a project in html and css, and I want my toolbar to stay on the page as the viewer scrolls down, but when the window is too skinny to display my full toolbar, I want to be able to scroll horizontally to see the rest of it

btw if it helps, I used a table element to make the toolbar

thanks, 
bye

Comment: what have you done beyond wanting things and using a table (which isn't good btw)?

Comment: You really need to provide a little more information to help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not that hard..

You just need:

```
position: fixed;
```

To make it able to scroll horizontally when the window is narrow, just set some arbitrary pixel length (however wide you intend the toolbar to be).